# Do autorelease pools have their own memory slabs to achieve fast deallocation?

Tags: objective-c

People say that autorelease pools free up autoreleased objects quickly. But there are two kinds of autoreleased objects:

1. Those that are autoreleased after init e.g. [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]
2. Those that are autoreleased during creation e.g. NSString stringWithFormat.

It seems to me that if Apple wanted to get the best performance, it would put the latter into a slab. However doing the same for the former is impossible, if an id is a memory pointer rather than an actual id.

At any rate, do autorelease pools have their own memory slabs to achieve fast deallocation of some objects?

Comment: So suppose I retain and save that autoreleased value from stringWitFormat.  What would happen to the object if it was in your "slab"?

Comment: Your 'slabs' were called 'zones' and they were abandoned.

Answer (score 3):

One can't tell this exactly (only an Apple engineer who will be fired after leaking this info), but if you look at alternative solutions/implementations of Foundation, for example, GNUstep, you'll see that "second-type" autoreleased objects are created in a way like:

```
+ (NSString *) stringWithString:(NSString *)otherString
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithString:otherString] autorelease];
}
```

However, autorelease pools still *can* implement their own methods to fast deallocate objects. You can, one more time, have look at GNUstep's NSAutoreleasePool.m in order to find out what it exactly does.

It also seems to me that you're not sure whether `id` is or is not a pointer. **It is**.

Comment: Actually, one can tell without someone being fired! See my answer, with links to the source :)

Comment: @Josh Caswell I do know that id's are pointers, but as always I was questioning what I know and admitting that I might not know everything. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Conveniently, this is open source! Check out http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/, specifically objc-arr.mm (for things like _objc_rootAlloc, which is what +alloc goes through), and from there you can see the following comment:

```
/* Autorelease pool implementation
A thread's autorelease pool is a stack of pointers. 
Each pointer is either an object to release, or POOL_SENTINEL which is 
  an autorelease pool boundary.
A pool token is a pointer to the POOL_SENTINEL for that pool. When 
  the pool is popped, every object hotter than the sentinel is released.
The stack is divided into a doubly-linked list of pages. Pages are added 
  and deleted as necessary. 
Thread-local storage points to the hot page, where newly autoreleased 
  objects are stored. 
*/
```

To directly answer your question though, no, no tricks like that are done. Autorelease pools merely manage pointers efficiently, not object storage.

Comment: Cool, thanks for clarifying. Seems that I overlooked parts of the Obj-C runtime...